# XAML binding doesn't work if the source is the main UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here's my code

**CustomClass**

```
public class CustomClass : Control
{
    public TabControl TabControl1
    {
        get { return (TabControl)GetValue(TabControl1Property); }
        set { SetValue(TabControl1Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TabControl1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TabControl1", typeof(TabControl), typeof(CustomClass), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWithoutSFControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWithoutSFControl"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <local:CustomClass >
        <local:CustomClass.TabControl1>
            <TabControl>
                <TabItem x:Name="tabItem" Header="Item1" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name1}"/>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </local:CustomClass.TabControl1>
    </local:CustomClass>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           // tabItem.DataContext = this;  //but uncomment this solves the problem!
        }
        public string Name1 => "Sync";
    }
```

Run the code, try to turn on the "TabControl Visibility" checkbox. Note that the "Sync" **doesn't** appear inside the TabItem, though it should because the TabItem's DataContext is set to MainWindow control.

To solve the problem, I need to set the `DataContext` from code behind by uncomment the line

```
// tabItem.DataContext = this;
```

But isn't the two completely equivalent? Why is this happening?

Comment: TabControl1 is just a property of your CustomClass. It is unclear why you think it should be visible at all. There is no code that would add it to the visual tree of your application.

Comment: @Clemens, but I do add it as a control in the Window class right? See the XAML.

Comment: You just set the CustomClass.TabControl1 property. That does not add the TabControl to the visual tree, unless there is any magic that you have not shown. Even if we assume such a magic exists, a property assignment like this does not form a logical or visual tree. That is why you should have observed a data binding error message like "*System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,  ...*" in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should render the `TabControl` that you set the `TabControl1` property to using a `ControlTemplate`:

```
<local:CustomClass>
    <local:CustomClass.TabControl1>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem x:Name="tabItem" Header="Item1" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
                <Label Content="{Binding Name1}"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </local:CustomClass.TabControl1>
    <local:CustomClass.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomClass">
            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding TabControl1}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </local:CustomClass.Template>
</local:CustomClass>
```

If you don't, you won't see the `TabControl` that contains the databound `Label` at all.

Note that if you indend to reuse the control, you should obviously define a default style/template for it.

Comment: What a bad suggestion. The XAML that renders the TabControl should obviously be part of the custom control, i.e in a default Style.

Comment: Sure. If there is a default style. Just move the template there then? The point is that you need to define a template.

Comment: I know. And you to. Why are you showing such a crap? Why don't you show where the default Style has to go?

Comment: What crap? The template? It's required for the `TabControl` to show and the binding to work as expected.

Comment: But it would never be declared like this. It makes absolutely no sense to have a custom control like this without a ControlTemplate in a default Style. You would have to set the Template property each time the control is used. Terrible advice.

Comment: `CustomClass` doesn't have a default `Style`. And the binding works assuming the `TabControl` is actually displayed which should answer the question.

Comment: I added a note about reusing the control to the answer.

Comment: How do you know that is has no default Style (you know, in Themes/Generic.xaml)? It sounds like OP can see the Label text in their control when they set the DataContext in code behind. But we can't be sure about that.